# How do I use the Rascal Evaluator to access Rascal functions from a compiled JAR?

Tags: java, rascal

I have the a jar with the following structure:

```
main-app/
├─ META-INF/
│  ├─ maven.org.rascalmpl.runmain/
│  │  ├─ pom.xml
│  │  ├─ pom.properties
│  ├─ MANIFEST.MF
├─ rascal/
│  ├─ Main.tpl
│  ├─ MyModule.tpl
├─ Main.rsc
├─ MyModule.rsc
```

and I'm writing an Evaluator to run function from the JAR, so far I have the following:

```
    final GlobalEnvironment heap = new GlobalEnvironment();
    final ModuleEnvironment top = new ModuleEnvironment("test", heap);
    Evaluator eval = new Evaluator(vf, System.in, System.err, System.out, top, heap);
    eval.addRascalSearchPathContributor(StandardLibraryContributor.getInstance());
    eval.addRascalSearchPath(URIUtil.rootLocation("std"));



    ISourceLocation tmp =  URIUtil.correctLocation("jar", "", "/path/to/runmain-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!");

    eval.addRascalSearchPath(tmp);

    eval.doImport(null, "Main");
    eval.doImport(null, "MyModule");
    
    System.out.println(eval.getHeap().existsModule("Main")); // Check if module has been added to heap

    eval.call("main", tmp, null);
```

When I try to run this, it just prints out `false`, and then the following exception:

`Exception in thread "main" org.rascalmpl.interpreter.staticErrors.ModuleImport: Could not import module Main: can not find in search path`

How can I access either the `.tpl` files or `.rsc` files in the JAR to call arbitrary functions?

P.S: When I compiled the JAR the RASCAL.MF was not included in the output, is it necessary?

Comment: just fyi, currently rascal is not compiled yet. the `tpl` files are type check files. We are getting close to having a compiler form, but that would just be regular class files.

Comment: Noted, I was mistaking them for the compiled form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `run-main` jar has a `META-INF/RASCAL.MF` in it with `Project-Name: run-main` in it, then the Rascal URI name resolver automatically registers `lib://run-main` and lets it point to the root of the jar. So that would enable you to do this:

```
ISourceLocation tmp =  URIUtil.correctLocation("lib","run-main","");
```

Instead of this, you can also use the `jar` scheme. But this requires you to find the jar file location:

```
jar+file:///path/to/run-main.jar/!/
```

After the `!` is where the path *into* the jar files starts, and where `.rsc` files can be found. The earlier `lib` scheme does exactly that, but automatically based on searching through the classpath for RASCAL.MF files.

Comment: Thanks this works and the lib is now being detected but I get a new error when I try to call a function like so: `eval.call("main", tmp, null);`. 

The error is: 
```Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "io.usethesource.vallang.IValue.getType()" because "v" is null
``` 
I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: I later fixed it by changing the call to `eval.call(null, "Main", "main");`

Comment: Ok thanks! That sounds like a good fix. Curious what your next step will be 